# I want to format the date time in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I want to display the date and time in a particular format as below :

"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"

But, I am getting the output as "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

I tried using the `edit.mask` property as follows :

`column(band=detail id=9 alignment="0" tabsequence=32766 border="0" color="0" x="300" y="450" height="100" width="1449" format="[shortdate]  [time]" html.valueishtml="0"  name=record_create_tms visible="1~tif(isnull(record_create_tms),0,1)" edit.limit=0 edit.case=any edit.autoselect=yes *edit.mask="YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM"* edit.imemode=0 font.face="Arial" font.height="-12" font.weight="400"  font.family="2" font.pitch="2" font.charset="0" background.mode="2" background.color="12632256" )`

But it is showing me syntax error when I try to save it. Please advise how to achieve my output?

Comment: Does `DateFormat='\''yyyy\/mm/\dd\'''` work for you (adding in the hours & minutes too)

Comment: @ScottJShea thanks for replying.. but can you please tell me exactly how to use it? Is it a property which is to be used along with edit like edit.DateFormat='\''yyyy\/mm/\dd\''' ?

Comment: In my question above .. i changed the format from "[shortdate] [time]" to "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm" and its working fine. :)

Comment: sorry I could not help but glad you figured it out

Answer (score 3):

You are confused between the *data format* that is used to *display* data and the *edit mask* that is used when *entering data* in edition.

I can see in the code you pasted that you changed the `edit.mask` but the `format` is still `[shortdate] [time]`.

Change the `Format`property from the `Format` tab page of the control properties to `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm`and it should work.

Comment: Damn, I just noticed that the OP gave the answer in a comment :P